# Is there a way to disable read.csv from treating an arbitrary number of columns with only "T" or "F" as boolean?

Tags: r, csv

Obviously if I know them in advance, I can just do something that I found in another answer:

```
data <- read.csv('test.csv', colClasses=c("sex"="character"))
```

If I need to load in a bunch of CSVs from different sources, I would rather not have to guess in advance which columns consist of this pattern or not, and I'd rather not have to run extra functions to determine this in advance or process the entire data frame after it's been loaded.

Comment: I'd just post process, after reading it in `bools = sapply(data, is.logical); data[bools] = lapply(data[bools] function(x) ifelse(x, "T", "F"))`

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a second pass?

Comment: @MaxCandocia - I don't think so. `read.table` and similar functions farm this work out to `type.convert` which is a function written in C code and not directly accessible.

Comment: Use colClasses="character". Then everything will be character.

Comment: I don't want to convert numbers to characters, though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple switch in `read.csv` or any of its variations, so you have to set the column type either when reading or after reading.

The best I can suggest is to use `dplyr::mutate_if` to detect whether columns are logical, then use `gsub` to convert TRUE or FALSE back to "T" or "F". I also prefer `readr::read_csv`, so strings are never factors, but `read.csv` would work the same in this example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

# test.csv
# a,b,c
# 1,T,T
# 2,F,T
# 3,T,F

data <- read_csv("test.csv") %>%
  mutate_if(is.logical, funs(gsub("RUE|ALSE", "", .)))

str(data)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2 3
 $ b: chr  "T" "F" "T"
 $ c: chr  "T" "T" "F"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the `stringsAsFactors` option:

```
data <- read.csv('test.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```